# How can I make a cascading plot in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I know how to make individual maps in ggplot2. But is there a way to programmatically cascade them like this? Willing to look at non-ggplot2 alternatives too.

[image]

Comment: I guess you want to end up with something integrated into a a web page and dynamic (user can click to select a graphic) or?

Comment: Not really. Static figure for publications.

Comment: Though, dynamic solutions are welcome too for learning purposes.

Comment: generate `n` static ggplot2 charts to png and stitch them together with `magick`

Comment: Make a list of grobs with gglot2 functions and assemble with grid functions.

Comment: I was wondering if there is a more elegant way of doing this.

Comment: Faceting seems like the elegant way... that way you could see all the data.